# VB.NET Desktop App Controls Changing Automatically

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

A VB.NET app using Visual Studio 2017 CE is behaving in very weird manner. Please check the video https://youtu.be/jXI1bnV7jlw

There is no other code in the app yet. Apart from automatically changing controls, there are empty items in combo boxes. I am sure that there are no empty records in the database.

Can anybody guide me what I am doing wrong here.

`Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
    Public Class frmAdd`

```
    Private sMapFile As String
    Private dtProvince, dtCities, dtZones, dtPlanTypes, dtGarageTypes, dtBuilders As DataTable

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLocateFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLocateFile.Click
        ' Select file and save the file path to sMapFile variable, to be used later while saving the data.
        ' Once file is selected, enable rest of the form to be filled.

        If fileSelectDialog.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK) Then
            sMapFile = fileSelectDialog.FileName
            txtMapFilePath.Text = sMapFile
            subFormEnabled()
        Else
            subFormEnabled(False)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub subFormEnabled(Optional shouldEnable As Boolean = True)
        grpBuilders.Enabled = shouldEnable
        grpLayout.Enabled = shouldEnable
        grpMeasurements.Enabled = shouldEnable
        grpRegion.Enabled = shouldEnable
        btnSave.Enabled = shouldEnable
    End Sub

    Private Function ValidateData() As Boolean
        'Everything except sMapFile is optional
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sMapFile) Then
            'Double check if file exists.
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Sub subPopulateData()
        'Populate Province
        dtProvince = DL.getProvinces()
        If (cmbProvince.Items.Count > 0) Then
            cmbProvince.DataSource = Nothing
            cmbProvince.Items.Clear()
        End If
        cmbProvince.Items.Clear()

        cmbProvince.DataSource = dtProvince
        cmbProvince.ValueMember = "id"
        cmbProvince.DisplayMember = "province_title"

        'Populate City
        dtCities = DL.getCities()
        cmbCity.DataSource = dtCities
        cmbCity.ValueMember = "id"
        cmbCity.DisplayMember = "city_title"

        'Populate Zones
        dtZones = DL.getZones()
        cmbZone.DataSource = dtZones
        cmbZone.ValueMember = "id"
        cmbZone.DisplayMember = "zone_title"

        'Populate Plan Types
        dtPlanTypes = DL.getPlanTypes()
        cmbPlanType.DataSource = dtPlanTypes
        cmbPlanType.ValueMember = "id"
        cmbPlanType.DisplayMember = "plan_title"

        'Populate Garage Type
        dtGarageTypes = DL.getGarageTypes()
        cmbGarageType.DataSource = dtGarageTypes
        cmbGarageType.ValueMember = "id"
        cmbGarageType.DisplayMember = "garage_title"

        'Populate Builder Company
        dtBuilders = DL.getBuilders
        cmbBuilderCompany.DataSource = dtBuilders
        cmbBuilderCompany.ValueMember = "id"
        cmbBuilderCompany.DisplayMember = "builder_company"


    End Sub

    Private Sub frmAdd_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        subFormEnabled(False)
        subPopulateData()

    End Sub
End Class
```

More Info:

- I am using SQLite database with official SQLite database engine.
- I have tried using access database but it also shows same issue.
- The app is based on .net framwork 4.5

Comment: Use your words.  What are we supposed to see as "weird" in a sped up video?  We have no idea how it is supposed to work - please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thanks for guiding me on how to post questions. I will keep that in mind next time I post something.
By the way, I have managed to solve the issue. It was temporary DataTable variable that was not being cleared for each table query.